How do I pass a template variable as string literal to Twig Filter's Barcode function?
I am using Drupal Barcode module to produce QR Codes and it is really effective.  I normally use a block or render a field, but today tried to create a code via Twig.
If is use this statement in Twig all is fine and the QR Code is rendered:
{{ "https://mylink.co.uk" | barcode(type='QRCODE', color='#000000', height=100, width=100, padding_top=0, padding_right=0, padding_bottom=0, padding_left=0, format='svg') }}

If https://mylink.co.uk is contained in a variable, say, {{ content.label }} (or any other variable already being rendered in the template), I cannot seem to pass it in without creating either a fatal error, or it just rendering a QR, that literally scans as the text {{ content.label }}
I feel like I have tried every combination but have not hit on it yet... What is the correct syntax?  The module documentation says 'While the above examples show us specifying a string literal "any string" to encode as a barcode, you may instead use any variable present in your template.' so I think it is possible?
UPDATE Following comments:
I am aware that {{ content.label }} is an array and that it needs to be converted.  Earlier in the template I use syntax like:
{{ attribute(content, 'myField')[0] }}

To strip stuff out because of that very reason.  It is how to get a String literal to pass to this filter that I am struggling with.
Here are what I have tried and the errors produced:
{{ {{ attribute(content, 'label')[0] }} | barcode(type='QRCODE', color='#000000', height=100, width=100, padding_top=0, padding_right=0, padding_bottom=0, padding_left=0, format='svg') }}
 | barcode(type='QRCODE', color='#000000', height=100, width=100, padding_top=0, padding_right=0, padding_bottom=0, padding_left=0, format='svg') }}

produces error:
The website encountered an unexpected error. Try again later.
Twig\Error\SyntaxError: A mapping key must be a quoted string, a number, a name, or an expression enclosed in parentheses (unexpected token "punctuation" of value "{". in Twig\ExpressionParser->parseMappingExpression() (line 96 of modules/custom/estimate/templates/estimate.html.twig).

Using:
{{ attribute(content, 'label')[0] | barcode(type='QRCODE', color='#000000', height=100, width=100, padding_top=0, padding_right=0, padding_bottom=0, padding_left=0, format='svg') }}

Produces the error:
The website encountered an unexpected error. Try again later.
TypeError: Drupal\barcodes\Template\Barcode::filterBarcode(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type string, array given, called in /var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/src/Environment.php(391) : eval()'d code on line 251 in Drupal\barcodes\Template\Barcode->filterBarcode() (line 78 of modules/contrib/barcodes/src/Template/Barcode.php)

I have tried adding quotes and concatenating to add quotes, so I could go on with many other examples of what I have tried. However I add quotes seems to give me a 'literal' QR of that code in quotes and not a link.

Show your code that doesn’t work. Include the error message in this post.

Because {{ content.label }} is no string. {{ content.whatever }} is a render array that can contain multiple values, < div > wrappers, HTML attributes, caching information,.....

If you are in a node template {{ node.field_name.value|barcode(...) }} (replace node with the entity type if it's a different template)

@mona lisa - thank you, fair comment - see update

@Hudri - I know, that is why I asked how to pass the variable in properly in the first place - see update

@4uk4 - Many thanks, tried this syntax but this produces an error

The Barcodes module already provides a field formatter for all relevant field types. Use it.


Alternatively you can use the Twig Field Value module to get the string first in Twig.
{{ content.field_name|field_value|barcode(...) }}


thanks, but I thought I could also just pass a variable already in a template directly to the filter?  I have a webform and I want to pass the page and all its existing parameters (so a current page token) to be displayed as a QR, so it is dynamic.  I have  installed Twig Field Value and tried your syntax, but still get:
'TypeError: Drupal\barcodes\Template\Barcode::filterBarcode(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type string, array given'  I'll take a look at creating a seperate field and seeing how I can try and incorparate that but its not ideal in my usecase

@ChumKui – This should be the first sentence in your question: I have a webform and I want to pass the page and all its existing parameters (so a current page token) to be displayed as a QR, so it is dynamic. otherwise we can just guess around.

Thanks @leymannx, sorry I should have been clearer but this is one particular use case.  I was hoping there was a general 'pattern' for supplying this info to the twig Barcode filter.  I have had a little look through the debugger and can see that Twig Field Value returns an array, even when using the 'raw_value'.
